# Can't get authorisation service (orbeon-auth) working in Orbeon 4 M11

Tags: orbeon

Orbeon/Tomcat newbie here - hope I'm just missing something obvious...

I'm on Orbeon 4 M11 & would like to try out the bundled orbeon-auth as an authorisation service, as described here: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/page-flow-controller/authorization.

I initially had trouble even getting orbeon-auth to work, but now I have it to the point where if I visit `http://localhost:8080/orbeon-auth` it will prompt for authentication and will return http 200 if I enter the correct credentials.  Now I need to configure my pages to use orbeon-auth.  According to the instructions in the link above I need to set this property:

```
<property as="xs:anyURI" processor-name="oxf:page-flow" name="authorizer" value="/orbeon-auth"/>
```

But I wasn't sure where to put the code. I thought it might go in page-flow.xml within the `<controller>` tags, but when I put it there & try to visit a page I get the "Orbeon Forms - An Error Has Occurred" error page.  I also tried putting it in properties-local.xml but that didn't do anything.  Hope someone can point me in the right direction...

Here is the entirety my properties-local.xml:

```
<!--
    This file is an empty template for your own properties-local.xml file. Please follow the instructions here:

    http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties
-->
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

    <!-- This is an example of property which overrides an existing property's default value:
    <property as="xs:NMTOKENS"
              name="oxf.xforms.logging.debug"
              value="document model submission submission-details control event action analysis server html"/>
    -->
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.Test.*.*" value="oracle"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.FieldReports.*.*" value="oracle"/>

    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.oracle.datasource" value="oracle"/>

    <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.oracle.create-flat-view" value="true"/>

    <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.summary.buttons.*.*" value="new print delete"/>

    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*" value="close clear print save save-locally submit workflow-review workflow-send"/>

    <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.edit.accept-post.*.*" value="true"/>

    <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.default-logo.uri.*.*"
                         value="/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/orbeon4pe/WEB-INF/resources/wb-logo.png"/>
    <property
        as="xs:anyURI"
        processor-name="oxf:page-flow"
        name="authorizer"
        value="/orbeon-auth"/>
</properties>
```

I have not altered `/WEB-INF/resources/page-flow.xml` or the orbeon-auth `/WEB_INF/web.xml` file - they are as they come out of the box.

Comment: That's right, properties go in your `WEB-INF/config/properties-local.xml`. Is this where you added the above property? If it is, could you maybe edit your question and put there the whole file content? Maybe there is some syntax error.

Comment: Added properties-local.xml - I hope that the behavior I'm expecting is correct - orbeon-auth should be called when the orbeon app does a PUT or POST, correct (given that defaults haven't been overriden)?  I looked at the Tomcat localhost_access_log and there are no requests to orbeon-auth except for when I explicitly visit the URL.

Comment: No, the authorizer is only called to authorize *external* requests. *Internal* requests from Orbeon Forms itself do not call the authorizer.

Comment: I see now.  I was confused...re-reading the documentation I'm seeing the distinction.  I added the "page-public-methods" property with a value of just "HEAD", and then a GET request did prompt a call to the authorizer.  Thanks for helping jog my brain in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused as to how this feature was supposed to function.  I overrided the default page public methods (GET & HEAD) by adding the following to /WEB-INF/config/properties-local.xml:

```
<property
  as="xs:string"
  processor-name="oxf:page-flow"
  name="page-public-methods"
  value="HEAD"/>
```

...and an external GET request did indeed cause a call to orbeon-auth first (no prompt for authentication, not sure if that's the expected behavior - orbeon-auth just returns 401/Unauthorized, then immediately 403/Forbidden, no prompt).

Comment: orbeon-auth returned 401 because by default, the orbeon-auth app is configured to authenticate only requests to Form Runner services, see the match on `/fr/service/*` in https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/descriptors/orbeon-auth-war/web.xml.

Comment: Edited answer to clarify behavior - my orbeon-auth web.xml doesn't match on `/fr/service/*` - there's only one `<security-constraint>` block, which matches on `/*` and includes `<auth-constraint><role-name>orbeon-service</role-name></auth-constraint>`.  For some reason when I visit `http://localhost:8080/orbeon-auth/` I'm prompted for credentials, but when I visit `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/`, it calls orbeon-auth but results in a 403/Forbidden, no prompt for credentials.

Comment: BTW, you can find more information about how properties work at http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties